# Date format for Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

I just created input date field and tried to change the format. but unable to achieve. is this possible to change the format?

**Code Snippet:**

```
<form>
<input value="i want to show 09/09/2015" /><br><br/><br/>
<input type="date" id="dt" value="2014-09-09"/>

</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HudMe/626/

I wanna show dd/mm/yyyy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below datepicker.
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Add below line your script.

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change `<input type='date'>` format so there is no way possible to change the format in `<input type="date">`.
 But you can use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ instead of it. see also http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

After you can change you date format like below :

`$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can change formate of dat by:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", <SPECIFY Date Formate here>);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Format not apply. Can you add in my fiddle. I have referred this toooo https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome it works fine !

For firefox

add small js

```
 (function(){
    var target = document.getElementById("dt");
    var val = target.getAttribute ('value');

    val = val.split("-").reverse().join('-');  
    target.setAttribute('value',val);
  })();
```

to your fiddle